# To display PDF in webview using google doc service in offline mode

Tags: android, pdf, webview, doc

I need to display PDF in Webview. I use google doc service to achieve the same (In online mode).

`mWebview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
String strPdf="https://www.adobe.com/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/pdf_open_parameters.pdf";
mWebview.loadUrl("https://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=" + strPdf);`

However my requirement is to achieve the same in offline mode. Since google now provides offline support for Google Docs how can I set the url of google Docs for offline mode. Could anyone help me out to achieve this

Comment: Did you solved your problem!?

Comment: Did you solved your problem.?