# Displaying PDF in WebView using Google Docs is not working anymore

Tags: android, pdf, google-docs

I'm using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18484549/to-display-pdf-in-webview-using-google-doc-service-in-offline-mode) solution to display document in `WebView` using Google Docs but it suddenly stopped working. When I'm trying do load that url in `WebView` `IntentPicker` dialog appears asking me about browser application I want to use. Is anyone experiencing this? Can this be fixed?

Comment: "When I'm trying do load that url in WebView IntentPicker dialog appears asking me about browser application I want to use" -- Google Docs is probably issuing a redirect. "Can this be fixed?" -- use a better solution for viewing PDFs, as there are many libraries available, in addition to using `ACTION_VIEW` to show the PDF in the user's preferred PDF viewer. Beyond that, you're welcome to experiment with a `WebViewClient` and `shouldOverrideUrlLoading()` to keep the redirected-to URL in the `WebView`.

Comment: Indeed, there's redirection to "https://drive.google.com/viewerng/viewer?embedded=true&url=" since last Google Services update, thanks. By the way there's only one library I know which can display PDF by web link (Radaee PDF Reader) and I don't know any application which can handle ACTION_VIEW Intent with web link to PDF file (I tested the most popular ones).

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative to Google Docs.

What you could try, is to use: **PDF.js** -> http://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/ **if you own a server of course.**

By setting a single and simple page in your server and just accomodate the code to read the parameter of the external PDF file and render it using pdf.js

Be careful with CORS for that I suggest you this page: http://enable-cors.org/server.html
Remember to enable CORS and all should run smooth.

just my grain of salt.